# TIME_TICK action not calling broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have written a simple broadcast receiver responding to `TIME_TICK` action .

When I add the action in the manifest file it is not calling the registered receiver but when I register the receiver in the java code it is being called.
I have a simple **onreceive** method.

```
public class mybroad extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("got", "broadcasted");
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "hurray broadcast got", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
```

receiver tag for manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.chapbasic.mybroad" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

when I operate with the following code it is working

```
public class broadact extends Activity
{
    IntentFilter ii;
    mybroad mb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mybroad);
    ii=new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.TIME_TICK");
    mb=new mybroad();

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mb, ii);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mb);
}
```

Kindly update why it is not being called from the manifest file registration.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

kindly go through the documentation that states.

You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with `Context.registerReceiver()` .

That is why you are not able to receive it when doing through manifest file.
thanks